# Video DIV background on :hover

Tags: html, css, video

I'm currently trying to create a site where a grid of thumbnails is loaded into a page and when a user (on desktop) hovers over a selected thumbnail, a small video plays in the background of the DIV.

At the moment my CSS is looking something like this:

```
.griditem {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #777;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 690px;
    min-width: 360px;
}

.video {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
}

.overlay {

    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}


.titles {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; /*important, forces to 100% height of parent*/
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;

}


.titles p {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: helvetica;
}

.griditem:hover .titles {
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity:1;
}

.imgspacer {
    width:100%;
}

.griditem:hover .video {
    display: inline;
}

.griditem:hover .imgspacer {
    display: none;
}
```

and my HTML

```
<div class="griditem" style="background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/80/Aspect_ratio_-_16x9.svg); background-size:100% 100%;">
<div class="imgspacer"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/JnW9SPx.png" width="100%" alt="Spacer 16x9" /></div>
            <div class="video">
            <video id="video" preload="none" muted autoplay loop poster="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/poster.png" style="width:100%; height:100%">
          <source id="mp4" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          <source id="webm" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm" type="video/webm">
          <source id="ogv" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv" type="video/ogg">
          <p>Your browser does not support HTML5 Video!</p>
            </video>
              </div>
    <div class="overlay">
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="titles">
     <p>BIG TEXT<br>
        small Title<p>
    </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

This seems to be working pretty well at the moment, but I'm wondering if it's possible to get the video to always start at the beginning (reset basically) when the `.griditem:hover` is triggered?

Also I've used `display:none` on the video DIV - does this mean all of the videos are being loaded in the background and are in effect 'playing?' - I'm worried about potential performance impacts when displaying lots of video as well as data usage! Is there a better way of doing this?

Here is a link to a fiddle of this: http://jsfiddle.net/jameshenry/0wo79wva/1/

Comment: You'll have to use JS to detect `mouseenter` and reset the `video.currentTime` to 0 to do this.

Comment: I'm sorry but my Javascript is a little lacking to say the least! do you have an example or a link where I could look up these functions?

Comment: Have a look at this for the basic idea. http://codepen.io/Lewiscowles1986/pen/MYeNBz

Comment: @Shikkediel Thanks so much for providing this demo - I've had a go and for some reason my script doesn't seem to be working? I'm sure I'm doing something stupid here but after playing with it for a few hours I'm no wiser - http://jsfiddle.net/jameshenry/0wo79wva/3

Comment: You were almost there but had forgotten to hook the fiddle up with the jQuery library. And the overlay is the element actually firing the mouseout. Hope that helps. http://jsfiddle.net/qheduf42/ @hj8ag

Comment: @Shikkediel Ah amazing, thank you so much for all your help! I thought (hoped) it would be something simple that I was just overlooking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved thanks to the help of @somethinghere and @Shikkediel and the following Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.overlay').mouseout(function() {
    $('#testvideo').get(0).currentTime = 0;
    });
});
```

Comment: You have a hash tag not belonging there before `testvideo`. Works nicely for the rest. ;-)

Comment: Totally copied and pasted the wrong Fiddle Javascript! Fixed now. Thanks for spotting that :)